# How to prevent jsonschema's validate() from connecting to internet

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am using the `jsonschema` package for validating the JSON file against the schema file. It appears it's trying to connect to `204.232.175.78 (pages.github.com
)` when using the `validate()` function. How to prevent this behavior?

BTW, the `jsonschema` version I am using is 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it. The issue is the JSON schema file contains the following line:

```
"$ref": "http://json-schema.org/geo"
```